# I have x number of BTC in Coinomi transferred to an account under my name. I was told that I need liquidity funds What do I need to withdraw BTC

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, fraud, money-transfer, funds

I have x number of BTC in Coinomi transferred to an account under my name.  I was told that I need liquidity  funds to withdraw them to my bank. Do I need a different wallet other than Coinomi.What do I need to withdraw BTC as the coins are visible but how do I tell if they are real,  I am completely without knowledge.